# debugging zsh completion method

Tags: shell, zsh

I am trying to debug a completion method.  This method is supposed to present with all the directories within these three folders.  I verified that compinit is loading it correctly.  tried tracing and i can't decypher most of it.

here is my completion function

```
#compdef c

_files -W $PROJECT/repos -/
_files -W $PROJECT/helm -/
_files -W ~/Code -/
```

and the function itself, c

```
#!/bin/zsh

cd "$PROJECTS/$1"
```

I don't get anything, nothing.  And i can't figure out how to debug it to figure out whats being put in _files to begin with.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic here. You may be able to get help on our sister site [unix.se].